# Mismatch between grails installed plugins list and intellij 11 list

Tags: grails, plugins, intellij-idea

I have a grails 2.0 app which I have installed the resources plugin into, when I look at the list of installed plugins in intellij it doesnt have it ticked, however if I do a 'grails list-plugins' it shows as being installed. Is there any way to refresh or correct the list in intellij? Other plugins have installed fine, and I have tried reloading the list in intellij.

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches does the trick, the lists now match (note : this does delete your local history also)

Comment: have you by chance checked out your project from svn trunk as "trunk"? This has caused quite a few oddities with grails in the past since all projects checked out as "trunk" from svn will be identified as the same project by grails under ~/.grails/VERSION/projects/trunk

Comment: It is a git project that was created from scratch, I did remove the plugin and then re-add it so I dont know if that was the problem but invalidating the caches worked. thanks.

Comment: well even from git the grails root dir name == project name conflict could occur if you had two projects with the same directory name, but based on your comment it does not seem likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to File -> Invalidate Caches fixes this problem, the lists now match (note: this does delete your local history also)

Answer (score 1):

IDEA looks into %USER_HOME%/.grails/2.0.0/projects/%PROJECT_NAME%/plugins to determinate which plugins are installed. Make sure that that folder contains unpacked 'resource' plugin.
If that folder contains unpacked plugin right click on grails project then select Grails -> "Synchronize Grails Settings" in the context menu.